# what happens when condition_timed_wiat time elapses when waiting for condition variable in linux

Tags: linux, variables, conditional-statements, synchronization

what happens when condition_timed_wiat() time elapses when waiting for condition variable in linux

```
struct timeval tv;
    struct timespec ts;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    ts.tv_sec = time(NULL) + timeInMs / 1000;
    ts.tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec * 1000 + 1000 * 1000 * (timeInMs % 1000);
    ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
    ts.tv_nsec %= (1000 * 1000 * 1000);

    n = pthread_cond_timedwait(&condition, &mutex, &ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns `ETIMEDOUT` (which is a nonzero value) and the mutex is not locked.